# How to avoid getInitialState() function used in useReducer( reducer, getInitialState() ) from running on every render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

See the snippet below.

By doing this:

```
React.useState(()=>getInitialState2());
```

You avoid running the `getInitialState2()` used in the `useState` on every render.

But that doesn't seem to work on the `useReducer` hook.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to avoid running a function that is used in the `initialState` parameter on the `useReducer` hook on every render?

```js
function App() {
  
  const [state,dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer,getInitialState());
  const [state2,setState2] = React.useState(()=>getInitialState2());
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        State: {state}
      </div>
      <div>
        State2: {state2}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: "INCREMENT"})}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: "DECREMENT"})}>-</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function getInitialState() {
  console.log("From getInitialState...");
  return 0;
}

function getInitialState2() {
  console.log("From getInitialState2...");
  return 0;
}

function reducer(state,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT": {
      return state + 1;
    }
    case "DECREMENT": {
      return state - 1;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running it on every render by calling it. To make the [initialisation lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization), pass a function. In addition, the lazy init is the 3rd param of `useReducer`. Whatever you supply as the 2nd param of `useReducer` will be passed to the lazy init function, but you can ignore it.

```
const [state,dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, null, getInitialState);
```

Or wrap it with an arrow function, if you need to initialize it with a value from props:

```
const [state,dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, null, () => getInitialState(props.something));
```

Demo:

```js
function App() {
  
  const [state,dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer,null,getInitialState);
  const [state2,setState2] = React.useState(()=>getInitialState2());
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        State: {state}
      </div>
      <div>
        State2: {state2}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: "INCREMENT"})}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: "DECREMENT"})}>-</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function getInitialState() {
  console.log("From getInitialState...");
  return 0;
}

function getInitialState2() {
  console.log("From getInitialState2...");
  return 0;
}

function reducer(state,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT": {
      return state + 1;
    }
    case "DECREMENT": {
      return state - 1;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the component is re-run every time a render occurs, one option is to retrieve the initial state only once *outside* the component:

```js
const initialState1 = getInitialState();
function App() {
  
  const [state,dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState1);
  const [state2,setState2] = React.useState(()=>getInitialState2());
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        State: {state}
      </div>
      <div>
        State2: {state2}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: "INCREMENT"})}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: "DECREMENT"})}>-</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function getInitialState() {
  console.log("From getInitialState...");
  return 0;
}

function getInitialState2() {
  console.log("From getInitialState2...");
  return 0;
}

function reducer(state,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT": {
      return state + 1;
    }
    case "DECREMENT": {
      return state - 1;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```